# Scalable view inside RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, scale

I have a scalable view inside ViewHolder, scale works like this:

```
private void applyScaleAndTranslation() {
     child().setScaleX(scale);
     child().setScaleY(scale);
     child().setTranslationX(dx);
     child().setTranslationY(dy);
}
```

If the view is placed in XML everything works fine, but in RecyclerView I can see that the view is outside the container.

I know about `RecyclerView.ChildDrawingOrderCallback`, I can change the order, but I can't disable it.

Is it possible to disable drawing outside container or maybe I can scale view with another way?

Things like `android:clipChildren="false"` didn't help.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image: The views overlap and clip into each other.]

Comment: Could you share your code? That it is reproducible for searching a proper solution.